# ios AppDelegate property declarations

Tags: ios, properties

After reading some tutorials online, I've seen 2 different ways to declare properties.
I'm wondering if one is more correct than the other:

Option 1:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *mytabs;

@end
```

Option 2:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject {
UIWindow *window;
UITabBarController *mytabs;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *mytabs;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

The first option uses Automated Reference Counting (ARC); the second one does not. Neither one is "more correct" than the other - the first one is simply more modern. You should use ARC unless you have strong reasons not to (e.g. because of the need to support legacy code on legacy platforms).

Here is a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) to learn more about ARC.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 has ARC enabled. Since iOS5 SDK it's the default option in Xcode.

**strong** means that the view controller will manage this variable

Here is a good [ARC tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1) for iOS5.

Option 2 has Automatic Reference Counting disabled.
 the view controller will **retain**  (increase the retain count) when the variable is set

Answer (score 0):

It used to be necessary to explicitly declare an instance variable to back each property. With the "modern" runtime, that's no longer required -- your @synthesize directive for the property will take care of creating the iVar if one doesn't already exist. Some people still keep the ivar declaration, either out of preference or just habit, and of course you'll see the ivars declared in older code. One benefit of doing it is that you can more easily see the values of your properties in the debugger.

The difference between using `strong` and `retain` is a matter of using ARC or not, respectively.